# Why do I see strange UDP fragmentation on my C++ server?

Tags: c++, sockets, networking, udp

I have build an UDP server with C++ and I have a couple questions about this.

Goal:

I have incomming TCP trafic and I need to sent this further as UDP trafic. My own UDP server then processes this UDP data.
The size of the TCP packets can vary.

Details:

In my example I have a TCP packet that consists of a total of 2000 bytes (`4 random bytes, 1995 'a' (0x61) bytes and the last byte being 'b' (0x62)`).

My UDP server has a buffer (`recvfrom buffer`) with size larger then 2000 bytes.
My MTU size is 1500 everywhere.

My server is receiving this packet correctly. In my UDP server I can see the received packet has a length of 2000 and if I check the last byte `buffer[1999]`, it prints 'b' (0x62), which is correct. But if I open `tcpdump -i eth0` I see only one UDP packet: `09:06:01.143207 IP 192.168.1.1.5472 > 192.168.1.2.9000: UDP, bad length 2004 > 1472`.
With the `tcpdump -i eth0 -X` command, I see the data of the packet, but only ~1472 bytes, which does not include the 'b' (0x62) byte.

The `ethtool -k eth0` command prints `udp-fragmentation-offload: off`.

So my questions are:

1. Why do I only see one packet and not two (fragmented part 1 and 2)?
2. Why dont I see the 'b' (0x62) byte in the tcpdump?
3. In my C++ server, what buffer size is best to use? I have it now on 65535 because the incomming TCP packets can be any size.
4. What will happen if the size exceedes 65535 bytes, will I have to make an own fragmentation scheme before sending the TCP packet as UDP?

Comment: TCP is stream-based, something like *'TCP packets'* does not exist. Indeed the underlying transport (IP) is packet based, but these packets are filled up as much as possible and then sent (if sufficient data available) – it can easily happen that you get more than one single packet of your custom protocol within one single read from the stream – or partial packages. If you want a packet based protocol over TCP you need to implement a suitable separation algorithm on your own!

Comment: I've been using [COBS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consistent_Overhead_Byte_Stuffing) for this purpose on several occassions – combined with an included CRC per message. You separate messages by the zero byte and the CRC makes sure – apart from catching transmission errors – that you can detect a partial message if by accident you started reception at a stuffed original zero byte...

Comment: You do know that MTU also counts the packet header(s)... right? With an MTU of 1500, the UDP packets, **including headers and everything**, cannot be larger than 1500 bytes... try to sent UDP payloads no larger than 1460... or even better, limit the payload to 1350 bytes, like QUIC does.

Comment: Why do you need to switch protocols at all? Just forwarding TCP data as TCP makes the whole stuff less error prone (though you still need to separate individual messages at second server). What's the reason for having two servers at all? Having both combined in one server *might* result in a less complex design.

Comment: Due to hardware limitations I cannot send over TCP, it needs to be UDP only

Comment: You are aware that UDP does not guarantee that packets are delivered in the order they were sent, or even that they get delivered at all? If you want to replicate a TCP stream over UDP, you more or less need to implement TCP on top of UDP.

Comment: Yeah I am aware of that. Due to a strong firewall I cannot send data back, even no TCP replies/acks. Thats why it needs to be UDP.

Comment: best firewall ever: prohibit communication :D

Comment: I see... My recommendation then is the following: Just don't care about messages on TCP-receiver side at all! Just send incoming chunks on TCP to UDP as are! *But* include a message counter into the UDP packets so that at UDP receiver side you can detect missing packages (OK, one single routing path, as you mention in an answer, so yo don't need to care for packages overtaking one another at least...). The only way to increase reception reception chances is by redundancy, duplicating any message at sender and ignoring duplicates – reduces transmission rate, so – well, up to you to decide...

Comment: Then you need a sufficiently large buffer on UDP receiver side to store at least one complete message – any one. Read into that buffer until you encounter a message being completely received, evaluate that message and then move the surplus bytes yet in the buffer towards its front – and make sure not to overwrite them on next read by providing an offset to the buffer pointer and subtracting it from number of available bytes.

Comment: I think the library I am using, is receiving the TCP stream into messages and providing those messages to me, which I have to sent as UDP. So the raw TCP chunks are beyond my reach.

Comment: Do you have source code available for that library? Possibly you might modify it to receive from UDP as well? If not, would it be an option to re-implement the protocol on your own, then on top of your own protocol that itself resides on top of UDP? If that's not an option either you might receive via UDP and open two further TCP sockets such that you simply re-send the data from UDP to TCP on loopback? That's less efficient, but a relatively simple solution – so an option, too, if you just don't want to invest that much effort the other options come with...

Comment: @Bart do you have "Generic Segmentation Offload" on (should be in ethtool list).

Comment: @Aconcagua I dont have those options im afraid, the TCP side are already existing servers not in my reach.

Comment: @Effie This "Generic Segmentation Offload" seems to be on

Comment: it will do the same thing as what you expect from "udp fragmentation offload".

Comment: Alright, but then I should see two pakets in tcpdump right? which I dont see.

Comment: no, because they will be fragmented after they are captured. if you turn it off, you should see two packets, which would most likely be fragmented IP packets.

Comment: So why do I get this ```bad length 2004 > 1472``` message? Does it sent the 2000 bytes in a single packet anyway?

Comment: By the way, the server doesn't send any replies to the client? Not being able to communicate backwards *might* impose yet further trouble!

Comment: @Aconcagua might sound weird, but this wont be a problem, this is intended :p

Comment: it does not "send 2000 bytes in a singe packet" over the wire. at some point it is fragmented and sent with whatever MTU of the link is. however this "some point" happens after the capture. the idea of segmentation offload is that in-OS packet processing has too much overhead per packet, so basically it ensures that packets within the OS are very large, to keep this overhead per "actual" packet minimal. So, segmentation offload causes "very large packets" to travel within the OS, and get fragmented as late as possible.

Comment: Bart, unless that firewall has intended to disallow any communication, it was not intended. Any application-layer protocol does include some sort of feedback. You cannot do flow control, you cannot do congestion control, you cannot have any idea of whether anything was delivered at all, you cannot have any idea if the communication partner has not crushed. This does work for TV broadcast, this does not work for any network i know of.

Comment: maybe you do not need congestion control, but just sending packets to someone, without any feedback on whether that someone can actually receive these packets is generally not the best idea.

Comment: I know it sounds weird but it realy is intended to work like this. No feedback, no congestion controll, no idea if it actually is delivered. All intended. But its not a big deal if a packet is not delivered.

Comment: you still need your own fragmentation scheme, so that the receiver can figure out which "message" was delivered and which was not. I will use the term mesage to indicate a logical single individable block from the application perspective. Since one message may require more that one packet, the receiver needs to distinguish them and reconstruct them (and filter out those with one packet missing).

Comment: there is no answer to what the buffer size should be. you need to look at upper layer protocol and figure out what this "message" can be.

Comment: This message can actually be larger then 1MB

Comment: there is also an option of using lower layer sockets (you can google for "raw sockets'), they will allow you to access IP packets directly. then you might be able to just get the packet, and swap tcp header. I think you will need to insert your own header with at least sequence numbers. This however may not work if any of the segmentation offloads/receive offloads is on (dunno who thought that tcp offloads are a good idea :D).

Comment: if messages are up to 1Mb, you probably need to get a stream of bytes and fragment it in normal chunks (MTU-size), with sequence numbers. And then the receiver needs to reconstruct the stream from sequence numbers and deal with missing packets, which it can only determine from the sequence numbers.

Comment: basically whatever TCP does (minus feedback / retransmissions / flow control)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, circumstances are more complicated as they appear from question, extracted from your comments there's the following information available:

1. Some client sends data to a server – both not modifiable – via TCP.
2. In between both resides a firewall, though, only allowing uni-directional communication to server via UDP.
3. You now intend to implement a proxy consisting of two servers residing in between and tunneling TCP data via UDP.
4. Not being able for the server to reply backwards does not impose a problem either.

My personal approach would then be as follows:

1. Let the proxy servers be entirely data unaware! Let the outbound receiver accept (`recv` or `recvfrom` depending on a single or multiple clients being available) chunks of data that yet fit into UDP packets and simply forward them as they are.
2. Apply some means to assure lost data is at least detected, better such that lost data can be reconstructed. As confirmation or re-request messages are impossible due to firewall limitation, only chance to increase reliability is via redundancy, though.
3. Configure the final target server to listen on loopback only.
4. Let the inbound proxy connect to the target server via TCP and as long as no (non-recoverable) errors occur just forward any incoming data as is.

To be able to detect lost messages I'd at very least prepend a packet counter to *any* UDP message sent. If two subsequent messages do not provide consecutive counter values then a message has been lost in between.

As no communication backwards is possible the only way to increase reliability is unconditional redundancy, trading some of your transfer rate for, e.g. by sending *every* message more than once and ignoring surplus duplicates on reception side.

A more elaborate approach might distribute redundant data over several packets such that a missing one can be reconstructed from the remaining ones – maybe similar to what [RAID level 5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_RAID_levels#RAID_5) does. Admitted, you need to be pretty committed to try that...

Final question would be how routing looks like. There's no guarantee with UDP for packets being received in the same order as they are sent. If there's really only one fix route available from outbound proxy to inbound one via firewall then packets shouldn't overtake one another – you might still want to at least log to file appropriately to monitor the inbound UDP packets and in case of errors occurring apply appropriate means (buffering packets and re-ordering them if need be).

Comment: Sounds about right, the routing is pretty simple:
```TCP server -> my UDP client -> firewall -> my UDP server -> other TCP server```
Distance between ```my UDP client``` to ```my UDP server``` is a couple centimeters

Comment: @Bart And how far is the firewall away??? If there are different routes possible to or from there, then packets might switch routes and thus possibly overtake one another!

Comment: Between those couple centimeters :p, there is only one possible route available to go from ```my UDP client``` to ```my UDP server```

Comment: does the app on "other tcp server" know how to handle missing data?

Comment: @Effie That's a crucial point. If it can just ignore missing/incomplete packages we are still fine. Otherwise – in this setup the 'other server' cannot re-request missing data – and the inbound proxy cannot either. Simulating a connection loss to the client is impossible as well due to the fire-and-forget nature of the outbound proxy. So this whole setup remains pretty vulnerable – still I do not see a better option than trying to improve reliability by redundancy...

Comment: well, let's be real, (1) packet losses on a wired connection are extremele rare (2) app does need to handle data errors anyway , since someone can launch a sequence number attack and cause TCP to accept packets it should not. I am having a little brain freeze on whether there is something to be handled differently on "my udp server" -> "other tcp server" connection, in a rare event is packet is actually lost, but this hould be a separate connection and it should be fine.

Comment: although i am extremely curious what is the real use-case of one-way firewall :)

Comment: @Effie `my udp server` -> `other tcp server` is not critical, this is a normal TCP connection. `my udp client` -> firewall should occur on two *internal*, **directly connected** network interfaces so that they cannot be accessed from outside -> prevents sequence number attacks at UDP level. Both firewall and `my udp client` (a TCP server) have separate external network interfaces. Then we should be pretty safe.

Comment: @Effie *'curious'* – me too...

Comment: @Bart did we clear up all the questions?

Comment: Yes I think its more clear now, I think I am going to implement some kind of own fragmentation scheme so I can split up the incoming TCP 'messages' (aka streams provided as a message to me from the library) and send those as UDP with a size of around 1460 bytes through the firewall. I seen someone saying 'limit them to 1350 bytes', why is this, why not just 1460 bytes?

Answer (score 0):

> The size of the TCP packets can vary.

While there is no code shown the sentence above and your description suggests that you are working with wrong assumptions of how TCP works.

Contrary to UDP, TCP is not a message based protocol but a byte stream. This especially means that it does not guarantee that single `send` at the sender will be matched by a single `recv` in the recipient. Thus even if the `send` is done with 2000 bytes it might still be that the first `recv` only gets 1400 bytes while another `recv` will get the rest - no matter if everything would fit into the socket buffer at once.

Comment: When I set the recvfrom buffer lower, lets say 1000 bytes, the other 1000 bytes will never be read, they are discarded. How do I make a distinction between the TCP stream data size and UDP packets?

Comment: @Bart You need a mechanism to split the incoming stream into individual messages. Then send each message in one single UDP packet. Keep an eye on messages being too large for one single packet. You then need to split single messages as well, and then things get complicated. How do you assure that none of the packets from the splitted message gets lost? How do you assure detecting lost packages? How do you assure receiving packets in correct order (if packets take different routing paths they might overtake one another)?

Comment: There is only one routing path, lost packets wont be a problem.

Comment: @Bart Still you need to be able to split and re-combine messages that are too large for single UDP packages (if they exist) – and you need to be able to detect limits of individual messages on incoming TCP side!

Comment: I think it would be possible to split up those TCP messages (little streams?), and rebuild them at the receiving side, some kind of own fragmentation. What do you mean with "detect limits of individual messages"? @Aconcagua

Comment: @Bart: If you just want to transfer the TCP byte stream via UDP you need to add your own reliability layer on top of UDP because packets might get lost, duplicated or reordered - no matter if you only have a single route or multiple. If you instead have some kind of messages in the TCP connection and want to transfer each message as a UDP datagram you need to implement some logic which extracts the messages from the byte stream - based some protocol specification which describes how messages are mapped to a byte stream.